# finding maximum in a range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table

```
2006 .5
2007 .6
2008 .4
2009 .7
2010 .4
```

I have given a range eg. `2006-2010`

I want result like this: Whenever a max value is present the following years will have max number unless the next number is bigger than previous.

```
2006-2010  2006 .5
2006-2010  2007 .6
2006-2010  2008 .6
2006-2010  2009 .7
2006-2010  2010 .7
```

So this is what I have tried:

I used a cross join and got

```
2006-2010  2006 .5
2006-2010  2007 .6
2006-2010  2008 .4
2006-2010  2009 .7
2006-2010  2010 .4
```

However, I am not getting the right result. Is there anything I should use to get max value than previous year. Not sure if I was able to explain this well.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring that out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Maybe ask a tutor?

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried? We aren't here to do your work for you but rather help you and steer you in the right direction.

Comment: I have posted what I have tried.

Comment: It's not clear what tables you cross joined. You've only mentioned one table. Maybe give your whole schema.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create table dates (year int, val float);
insert into dates values (2006,.5); insert into dates values (2007,.6); insert into dates values (2008,.4); insert into dates values (2009,.7); insert into dates values (2010,.4);
select * , (select round(max(val),1) from dates d2 where d2.year<=d1.year) as max  from dates d1;
```